# Why am I getting a UnknownHostException?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to instantiate an URL object (in Java) with the address: http://www.cornellrams.com/rss.php. It gives me an UnknownHostException. The site is live and well, but I can't access the feed. Any ideas why it doesn't like me? This is on Android. I do have the internet permission in the manifest.

Comment: I don't do Android, so I can't tell how to fix it, but I can tell that the underlying technical cause of this particular exception is that the hostname cannot be resolved to an IP address. If the hostname is for sure correct, then this is in turn often a DNS server issue on the network connection you're using.

Comment: Can you able to access internet from android browser?.

Comment: I can access the browser and browse content. I can even stream music from it.

Answer (score 0):

May be `firewall` is blocking network connection for the `emulator`. You need to set /allow emulator to use network connection and also set network connection `sharing`.

Comment: I have access to the internet. That is not an issue. Internet works on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the url ... chances are there's a typo in it somewhere.  If not then DNS issue, but you can access the web browser ... so unlikely if you can browse.

Ensure you are using the correct protocol i.e http/https depending on whether you are using ssl

I often get issues with the wifi on my samsung gadgets. not sure what it is perhaps a request gets stuck so I'm forced to turn wifi off then back on again ... it happens a lot (especially with twitter app).

Also make sure that your timeout's are generous especially if using 3g rather than wifi.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem once with my emulator. Restarting the emulator helped (maybe also with  cleaning build).